# Accidentally ran the wrong command in mac terminal. What does mv * .. do?

Tags: bash, macos

I accidently ran command

```
mv * ..
```

instead of

```
mv * .
```

on my mac. Now I cannot find the files. What did the command do?

Answer (score 2):

`..` is the parent directory, i.e. the directory one level higher in the hierarchy. For example, if you are in the directory `/a/b/c/`, then `..` means `/a/b/`.

`mv * .` doesn't make any sense - you can't move files onto themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The mv command stands for move. You moved your files to the directory above where they were located. You can always type

```
man mv
```

to get a description of a unix command.

Comment: i told you what .. means. It means the directory one above where the files are.

Comment: so mv * ..  moves all the files in that directory to the directory one above where the files are.